# Entity Framework 4: Table per Type inheritance problem on insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I have simple model with a "BaseEntity" and a derived "Fund" entity.
When I try to insert a new fund:

```
HybridModelContainer container = new HybridModelContainer();

//Create new Fund
Fund fund = new Fund();
fund.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
fund.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
fund.Name = "Fund 1";
fund.Number = 1;
container.BaseEntities.AddObject(fund);

container.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error:

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'HybridData.dbo.BaseEntities'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated."

It seems that the ID assigned to the fund entity is not inserted into the BaseEntity table. Why not?

I did this "model first". If I design the database first, and create the model from it, everything works fine....But I need model first!

[image]

Also...why isn't there an `ObjectSet` for "`Funds`" in my `DataContext` (i.e., `container.Funds`)? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is `HybridModelContainer`? Post a screenshot of the mapping details for your `Fund` entity.

Comment: That's just the name of the DataContext.

Comment: @SolarX: Could you please post the screenshot that I mentioned?

Comment: Most likely your mapping is wrong. Is your `Fund.Id` a FK to `BaseEntities.Id`? It should be. That said, TPT mapping to a core base type will not end well.

Comment: @Adam: I've posted the screenshot.

Comment: @Craig: Why wouldn't it end well? What is the downside?

Comment: @SolarX: See Edit section in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can only answer for the second part of your question: "Also...why isn't there an ObjectSet for "Funds" in my DataContext (i.e., container.Funds)?"

It's normal that the ObjectContext has only an ObjectSet of the base class in your class hierarchy. There isn't really a need for an ObjectSet of the derived classes. For adding and deleting derived objects to/from the ObjectContext you can just use the `AddObject` and `DeleteObject` methods of the `ObjectSet<BaseEntity>` / `BaseEntities` as you already did in your example.

For querying derived objects you can leverage the `OfType` method of the ObjectSet. It returns an ObjectQuery of the derived type where you can build further queries upon:

```
ObjectQuery<Fund> query = container.BaseEntities.OfType<Fund>();
```

(The first part of your question sounds like a mapping error between the storage and the conceptual model. It might have a better cif you could show the relevant parts of your edmx file.)

**Edit: Possible solution to the first part of the question:**

I've created your example with Model-first in VS2010 and I could reproduce your issue. The problem seems to be related to the fact that the primary key in your model isn't an `Int32` but a `Guid`. When you add a new Entity to the Model the designer always proposes an `Int32` as primary key with `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `Identity`.

If you change now the type of the key in the model designer from `Int32` to `Guid` but leave the `StoreGeneratedPattern` unchanged being `Identity`, the DDL creates a database in SQL Server with `Id` set to type `uniqueidentifier` but Identity specification for that column is "No".

So, when EF sends an INSERT command to the DB it "thinks" from the model definition the primary will be autogenerated in the DB and doesn't send the Guid to the DB which you have assigned in code. But the DB doesn't create the key, resulting in a NULL value for the key. Hence the error we get.

Solution: Set in the model designer for the `Id` property of `BaseEntity` the `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `None`. For me it worked then. Of course, you are responsible then to always assign a Guid to `Id` before you add a new object to the ObjectSet, but that seems to be what you want anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the same thing with a database first approach and everything works find (after removing relations and setting up inheritance in the model). I just can't get this to work with the "model first" approach. But we do want to go model first. Any idea?

Comment: @SolarX: Perhaps I found the solution: See the Edit in my answer above.

Comment: I will try this as soon as as I get of my meetings... I was expecting it to be a problem with Guid. It's curious that I couldn't find anything on that in the web. Thank you so much for your help !!